# iphone - how to refresh a uiview with a scrollview?

Tags: ios4

any advice welcome! :)

My screen design is landscape with text on the left (this is in the main view) and a scrollview on the right (which contains an interactive map image)

The mainviewcontroller contains the scrollview as an outlet.
In the scrollviewcontroller I add a 'map' view into the scrollview.
In the mapviewcontroller I update an array in the appdelegate, depending on the user input.

I would now like to refresh the main uiview that contains the scrollview to display the updated text from the appdel array - whenever the user clicks a button.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your view's -(void)setNeedsDisplay method to cause it to redraw.

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

See Apple's reference documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCADHC

Comment: Hi :) yes, I've come across this method before and have read the documentation, but am still not getting it to work... I call the method like: [mainView setNeedsDisplay]; in my mapViewController but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: if I have 2 viewcontroller classes with a uiview as an IBOutlet in each, what would be the correct syntax to reference the second uiview in the first viewcontroller ?

Comment: for example, do I need to include something like this before calling setNeedsDisplay?
-#import "MainViewController.h";

MainViewController *mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[mainvView setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: thing is, even trying to alter something simple like a button in the mainView isn't working like: [mainView.button1 setHidden:YES]; so expecting I have screwed up the syntax ;) help!

Comment: You shouldn't really be directly referencing the view of another UIViewController from within the context of another UIViewController. That is a fundamental concept in the Model, View, Controller pattern. A view controller should manage it's own view, and that view's subviews. If you need to update the view with data from outside the scope of that view controller, you should provide a method that accepts that data and update's the view. If that's not helpful, perhaps you can provide a code example with a bit more detail about what you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `viewWillAppear` from the other viewcontroller